# Cut one line on two

Tags: cut

I want to delete one line on two with linux such that

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

becomes

```
A
D
E
```

how can I make it work?

Comment: Do you want to delete the lines 2 and 3, or every 2nd and 3rd line out of five?

Comment: I want to delete all "pair" lines, every first line out of two.

Comment: Then it should be A/C/E instead of A/D/E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you want to get every odd line. For this, you can use many tools:

```
awk 'NR%2' file
```

this takes into account the number of record (`NR`, that is, number of line in this case) and evaluates if it is multiple of 2 or not. If it is, the condition `NR%2` is false, so that lines are not printed; otherwise, they are. Note the default behaviour of `awk` is `{print $0}`, so it can be omitted: `1` is the same as `{print $0}`.

```
sed '0~2d' file
```

Just delete every line that is multiple of 2. You can also inhibit the printing with `-`n and explicitly print those lines not being multiple of 2:

```
sed -n '1~2p' file
```